# Как перенести проект метеора на другой компьютер? (Meteor.js)

Tags: meteor, проект

Версия метеора на обоих компах 1.5.1

Так выглядит вся папка с проектом

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При копирований всей папки с проектом с одного компа на другой, в терминале выдаёт ошибку при запуске проекта

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Получается в тупую скопировать нельзя проект.

Но если на втором компе создать проект заново, и скопировать туда только папку client(где лежат все html,css,js файлы), то работает, но выдаёт ошибку 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
там у меня выводится имя и логин пользователя, такое ощущение что ей не хватает БД, но его нет в папке client.

как быть,народ? как правильно переносить проекты Meteor.js?

Answer (score 0):

Переносить приложение на метеор стоит также как вы его в репозитории храните:

1. Папку `.meteor\local` добавляем в игнор и не переносим ее (остальные файлы в папке `.meteor` переносим обязательно)
2. Папку `node_modules` тоже добавляем в игнор и не переносим (хотя можно перенести, но оно того не стоит)
3. После переноса приложения запускаем `meteor npm i` чтобы установить зависимость (если папку `node_modules` не переносили)

После этого приложение должно запуститься без проблем.

P.S. Если нужно перенести базу то она хранится в `.meteor\local\db` ее тоже можно перенести (но в репозиторий не добавлять).