# Не могу запустить проект meteor

Tags: javascript, windows, node.js, npm, meteor

В общем после того как ввожу npm run start в терминал появляется вот такая ошибка

[image: ошибка в терминале]

Версии node.js,npm,git,meteor обновлены.ВАЖНО: на Linux-e проект запускается без проблем.

Лог ошибки:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
 1 verbose cli [ 'E:\\nodejs\\node.exe',
    1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\Aliaksei\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
    1 verbose cli   'run',
    1 verbose cli   'start' ]
    2 info using npm@5.3.0
    3 info using node@v8.2.1
    4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
    5 info lifecycle swissproperty@~prestart: swissproperty@
    6 info lifecycle swissproperty@~start: swissproperty@
    7 verbose lifecycle swissproperty@~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
    8 verbose lifecycle swissproperty@~start: PATH: C:\Users\Aliaksei\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;E:\work\TheNorthRemember\swissproperty\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\;C:\WinAVR-20090313\bin;C:\WinAVR-20090313\utils\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\runtime\win64;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\polyspace\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;E:\Yarn\bin;E:\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Git\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\Aliaksei\AppData\Local\.meteor\;C:\Users\Aliaksei\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Git\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
    9 verbose lifecycle swissproperty@~start: CWD: E:\work\TheNorthRemember\swissproperty
    10 silly lifecycle swissproperty@~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'meteor run' ]
    11 silly lifecycle swissproperty@~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
    12 info lifecycle swissproperty@~start: Failed to exec start script
    13 verbose stack Error: swissproperty@ start: `meteor run`
    13 verbose stack Exit status 1
    13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Aliaksei\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:289:16)
    13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
    13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:213:7)
    13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Aliaksei\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:40:14)
    13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
    13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
    13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:921:16)
    13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
    14 verbose pkgid swissproperty@
    15 verbose cwd E:\work\TheNorthRemember\swissproperty
    16 verbose Windows_NT 6.3.9600
    17 verbose argv "E:\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Aliaksei\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "start"
    18 verbose node v8.2.1
    19 verbose npm  v5.3.0
    20 error code ELIFECYCLE
    21 error errno 1
    22 error swissproperty@ start: `meteor run`
    22 error Exit status 1
    23 error Failed at the swissproperty@ start script.
    23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
    24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Выложите лог ошибки

Comment: Помогите.Прошу(

Comment: Вы пробовали создать новый проект и запустить его? Работает? Попробуйте запустить свой проект из консоли с правами админа, возможно не хватает прав.

Comment: Работает.Права админа не помогают.

Comment: Ну значит у вас проблема с проектом, а не метеором. Вероятно, вы его неправильно разворачиваете. Какие файлы проекта вы переносите? Я недавно выкладывал инструкцию по переносу проекта на метеор, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/694928/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80-meteor-js попробуйте по ней